# Line breaking when function is called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As I was helping another member on here I ran into a question of my own.

Take a look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/93fBP/8/

And shrink the pane back and forth. You'll notice the menu items populate the more menu as they should.

However I'm doing this at the bottom of my JS:

```
detectOverflow();
$('.overflow-items ul').reverseChildren();
detectOverflow();
```

Because if I only call the function once this happens on initial load when the menu is in a certain position:

http://note.io/1pkrydl

Try it for yourself by removing one of the function calls like so:

```
detectOverflow();
$('.overflow-items ul').reverseChildren();
```

The issue fixes itself as soon as you start resizing which I image is because at that point the function is called again.

I spent a few hours trying to clean up my code and figure out why this might be the case but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "More" menu, o more precise, the `padding-right` attribute, when items position are review the Menu is hidden and the nav wrapper doesn't have "padding-right" style applied, so, the 3rd element is placed in the first nav row, but when the More menu is shown  and the padding applied, the 3rd element is wrapped to the a new line.

I'd put an initial padding-right value to compute items position: http://jsfiddle.net/93fBP/11/

```
$('.primary-nav-wrapper').css('padding-right', 40);

// Initial run of detect Overflow
detectOverflow();
$('.overflow-items ul').reverseChildren();
//detectOverflow();
```

I've changed a bit the way how the items are passed to "more" menu, to avoid a secondary effect once the patch is applied, due to the items are moved immediately, there are cases where the element, for instance, the third one, that is large, is moved to "More" menu but the 4th is shown in the main navbar because It's smaller. so to fix that, I move all elements to "more" menu once all items has been processed. The new code shouldn't have any issue about that.

The new code in detectOverflow() is:

```
    var more_items = []
    $('.primary-nav li').each(function () {
        if (more_items.length > 0) {
            more_items.push($(this))
            return;
        }
        var $this = $(this),
            elemPos = $this.position().top - ulPos;
        // Figure out the width of the combined li margins
        liTotalWidth = liTotalWidth + parseInt($(this).css('marginLeft'), 10) + $(this).outerWidth();

        // Check if the link dropped down to the second line
        // If it did put it in the more menu
        if (elemPos > 0) {
            more_items.push($this);
        }
    });

    $(more_items).each(function() {
        $(this).prependTo('.overflow-items ul');
        liCount = $('.primary-nav li').length;
    });
```

Comment: This only seems to happen with your edit, in the prior version this wasn't happening.

But I think you're right about the menu being the source of the issue, just have to figure out a way to dynamically insert that value as the menu is not always present.

Comment: @MarioD, please, take a look to the new version, The issue was fixed.